# How do I calculate GPS distance accurately in Python

Tags: python, gps

I am trying to update distance traveled between GPS coordinates. My error is that the GPS can move short distances while sitting still. I am currently adding the new coordinates to a list every second, calculating the distance between this second and last second, then appending the distances to a new list then add them all together.

The issue is that the small movements in distance while standing still keep accumulating. Does anyone know the proper way to do this?

```
self.breadcrumbs = []

#Calc Linear Distance GPS
while 1:
    report = gpsp.get_current_value() #Retrieves GPS Values
    try:
        self.lat = report.lat
        self.lon = report.lon
        self.latlon = (self.lat, self.lon) #Put lat lon into tuple 
        self.breadcrumbs.append(self.latlon) #Append lat lon to breadcrumb list
        breadcrumb_distances = [] #Holds distances between latlon data points
        for i, b in enumerate(self.breadcrumbs):
            current_location = b
            last_location = self.breadcrumbs[i - 1]
            miles = geodesic(current_location, last_location).miles 
            feet = miles * 5280 #convert to feet
            breadcrumb_distances.append(feet)
        cumulative_distance = round(sum(breadcrumb_distances),2)
        print(cumulative_distance)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
    sleep(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no single "right" way to do this.  The problem is that when you are moving very slowly, the "erroneous" movement overwhelms what the user would perceive as the actual movement.   It becomes a tradeoff between taking data that is in error and dropping data that represents actual motion.  The problem increases the faster you take data and the slower the velocity.

One method is to set a minimum distance that will cause you to log new data.  If the new point is within some distance ϵ of the previous one, drop the point.  For good choices, this will ignore motion when actually stopped.  You then need to not care about the time between data points, or you need to log the time for points (or somehow indicate the location and duration of the gaps).  If the problem is due to stopped periods, this may be the best.

Another method is to reduce the logging frequency.  For some applications, backing off to 5s or similar may be sufficient.

Comment: I actually have already implemented your suggestions. Just wondering if there was a better way.

Comment: I don't know of any python modules that code those (or other) techniques up.  Maybe someone else will know of one that does that or a similar post-processing.